# Select image from gallery with transparent background in android

Tags: java, javascript, android

I open image from gallery,then I crop the image or when I set the image to imageview ,background is show, this is my issue

I create the image with transparent background in android.

how it is possible.

Comment: which background show, imageview's background or image's background ?

Comment: The question is not clear! Anyway, if you want to select transparent images from a gallery then upload only transparent images inside gallery via code!